# How to Get id of current post to add comments to it

Tags: php, mysql, database, flask, social-networking

This may be a possible duplicate but please do not downvote me .
I have made a few simple web apps but none of them requured this kind of mechanism, so a little stuck.

Let says i display recent posts on the homepage and there is a comment section right below each post that u can post comments via ajax. So how do i get the id of that post so i can use it in my insert statement. I thought of having that data lying somewhere in a hidden field but it could be tampered with. Suggestions?

Comment: Sure it could be tampered with but thats the only way you can get it.

Comment: Hi. Not sure but Is that sarcastic? Or is that seriously the only way

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't worry about doing some complex obfuscation unless it becomes a problem. I think it's a ROI, if there is a lot to lose by not doing something, then do it. What is the worst case scenario? Someone automating a bunch of comments or what are you worried specifically about happening?

Comment: my fear is. Lets say a user is not supposed to be commenting on posts from people he is not friends with. Since the id's are auto incremented and he tampers any posts id which was lets say 20 to 589(post from someone he is not a friend of) he could still comment on their post by a simple tamper..

Comment: Oh, that sounds more like you need to have a system in place which includes session and permissions checks vs a tampering issue.

Comment: You could use [hashid](http://hashids.org/) if you're worried about database id disclosure, but another problem you will encounter with multiple forms/comment inputs, which is more of a security issue would be that you would need to generate a CSRF token for each POST of a comment, so you would need to know how to do this in your request and response headers in your ajax code to maintain a valid token.

Comment: Nope, not sarcastic. You have to send the id, your backend should validate the data though. If user X doesn't have permission deny the request and dont do anything with it.

Comment: I think as all of you have suggested i will add a few validations to the commenting mechanism. Thanks for your suggestions. Really helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reason to worry about that, you could publish a token id which you check against a list of arbitrary valid ids and then discard requests with an invalid id.

Edit: I mean in a way that it's not possible (within reason) to just tamper with the token id and expect to come up with a valid id of course.

Comment: Even the tokens could only verify to the fact that the posts exist and thr user doesnt create a comment to a post that doesnt exist. See mymain problem in my reply to @rasclatt

Comment: re: your OP comment: add a check when the request is made ? as in, check that the user is allowed to comment on the post before you write it in the db.

Comment: The Rich(Google or Facebook's) way of doing this would definetely be by probably adding a few more validation queries etc. But i am a little light on my server and was wondering if it would be possible to do it with as few resources as possible...

Comment: It is really rather simple. We are all assuming you have in place a user authentication system of some sort, and a session to keep track of the current user id. Before you insert the new comment in the db, check that the current user is allowed by your rules to post on that comment. In your case, I suppose you would check if current user is friends with post owner. Else, discard the operation, log it, or whatever you want.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do those validations. But i guess thats the only way to maintain some security. Thanks for your answers.. Really helped.